# Why does Dijkstra's algorithm not account for updating node distances after expanding a node?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

Why does Dijkstra's algorithm not re-evaluate/re-expand nodes who have been expanded and later had their weight changed?

For example, in the accepted answer of [this question (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799172/negative-weights-using-dijkstras-algorithm), if the algorithm simply understands that d(b) has been updated and it should re-expand b, the shortest cost would be found.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Since Dijkstra's algorithm always expands the shortest path first, the first time we reach a node will be along the shortest path to that node. That is the key insight that allows the algorithm to be efficient compared to a breadth-first-search.

There is no way to construct a graph where no costs are negative and there exists a path from `a` to `b` shorter than the one Dijkstra's algorithm finds.

Comment: So you're saying that if it were to re-expand an already expanded node after its value has changed it would make the algorithm less efficient than other algorithms, eliminating its purpose?

Comment: It would be less efficient, yes. Also, looking at new paths to an already reached would be completely useless, since we've already found the shortest path to that node.

Comment: If a node with a larger distance from the starting node has a negative path then we have not necessarily already found the shortest path.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm assumes there are no negative cycles, as I mentioned in the answer above. If you need to handle negative cycles, use `Bellman–Ford algorithm` instead.